# Datatable request paramter is null prototype object

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatable

I try to datatable ajax request. But in server, console logging as below.

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  draw: '1',
  'columns[0][data]': 'no',
  'columns[0][name]': '',
  'columns[0][searchable]': 'true',
  'columns[0][orderable]': 'true',
  'columns[0][search][value]': '',
  'columns[0][search][regex]': 'false',
  'columns[1][data]': 'projectName',
 ...
'search[value]': '',
  'search[regex]': 'false',
  projectName: ''
}
```

This is my client's js function.

```
function getSettingInfo() {
    $('#settingInfo').show();

    $('#settingInfo').DataTable({
        destroy: true,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        searching: false,
        ajax: {
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/setting/getSettingInfo',
            data: function(d) {
                d.projectName = '';
            }
        },
        iDisplayLength: 10,
        order: [[0, 'desc']],
        pagingType: 'simple_numbers',
        columnDefs: [
            { className: "dt-head-center", targets: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] },
            { className: "dt-center", targets: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] },
        ],
        columns: [
            { data : "no", width : '6%'},
            { data : "name", width : '13%'},
            { data : "key", width : '17%'},
            { data : "description", width : '32%'},
            { data : "use", width : '32%'}
        ]
    });
}
```

and server router's js

```
router.post('/getSettingInfo', async function (req, res) {
    let param = req.body;
    console.log('\n\nparam', param);
}
```

How can I request a null object as a normal object type?
In the last js file, **param.order** is logged as **undefined**.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found it.

**In app.js**

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

'extended : false' caused like json.stringify ajax request.
So, I change false to true.